# make a flutter application work on ios device

Tags: ios, flutter, apk

We have a Flutter app and we succeeded to make an `apk` file and make it work on a real Android device. We want to make the same thing on an IOS device.
we tried to use the command: `flutter build ios --release` , but it didnt work.

we work on windows computer and the goal is to create a file, send it to an IOS device and and dwonload it to the device.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have build the ios app ipa file will be generated. Just make a zip of that
make a Diawi  using https://www.diawi.com/.
You have to add iphone UDID in diawi .
Then you can able to install app in Iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag and drop your ipa file into https://appshare.live, it creates the link and you can send it to your target users to quickly install.